# Uploading file is not working with mp3 and mp4

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

here this is working with images but not working with mp3,mp4,I've changed the upload_max_size in .ini file also but that doesn't work

```
 $target_dir = "videos/";
 echo '<br>';
 echo $target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
 $uploadOk = 1;

 echo '<br>';
 //$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image 
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 echo 'started';
 echo '<br>';    
 echo $check = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
 if($check !== false) {
    move_uploaded_file($check,$target_file);
    echo 'Uploaded';
     } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    } 
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like you should also set the other php.ini variables for example:

- post_max_size = 200M
- upload_max_filesize = 200M

But then you could always send file larger than this limit (then the superglobal _POST and _FILES are empty) so the best practice I think is to use sth like this

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST) &&
     empty($_FILES) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 0 )
{      
  $displayMaxSize = ini_get('post_max_size');

  switch ( substr($displayMaxSize,-1) )
  {
    case 'G':
      $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
    case 'M':
      $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
    case 'K':
       $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
  }

  $error = 'Posted data is too large. '.
           $_SERVER[CONTENT_LENGTH].
           ' bytes exceeds the maximum size of '.
           $displayMaxSize.' bytes.";
}
```

The code ant explain could be found here: http://andrewcurioso.com/blog/archive/2010/detecting-file-size-overflow-in-php.html

Comment: Got it.thank you It was the post_max_limit that was 3M set in my php.ini file.